Adverbial clause as a modifier


He is in the room because he is tired.
He is here because he needs money.


Here bolded clauses are modifying what?
Are these modifying the verb or something else?
Nowadays, I am so disturbed with the adverbial clause.
Before I thought all adverb clauses modifies only the verb.

As @jamesk wrote yesterday, to be honest Salim, these questions are getting a little bit tiresome and repetitive.

This question is similar to: Adverbial clause as main clause vs verb modifier. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
